# how to fetch php for loop variable in js confirm alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have few image which i am fetching from by directory`$files = glob("images/image/$til/$subtil/*.*");`. i have to delete one image from all image and i wants to show a confirm alert like yes or no. if yes fetch the vale of image and pass it in to next page. `$detatil="delete.php?image=$image&til=$til&subtil=$subtil";`this is the variabel i have to fetch and and post in next page

```
<?php
$subtil=$_GET['subtil1'];
$til=$_GET['til1'];
 $files = glob("images/image/$til/$subtil/*.*");
            $count=count($files);
            for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
            { 

              echo "<div class='pitem entry item-w1 item-h1'  style='padding: 15px;'>";

              $image = $files[$i];
              echo "<img src='".$image."' class='img-responsive' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid black;'>"."";
              echo "<br>";
              echo"<span style='float: center;padding-top: 10px;'><button type='submit' onclick='myFunction()' name='submit' value='Send' class='btn btn-primary'>Delete</button></span>";
              $detatil="delete.php?image=$image&til=$til&subtil=$subtil";
              //echo $detatil;
              echo "</div>";
?>

            <script>

            function myFunction() {
                  var r=confirm("Do you want to leave page!");
                if (r)
                {
                    //write redirection code
                    window.location = "<?php echo$detatil?>";
                }
                else
               {
                    //do nothing
                }    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
            }
            </script>  

            <?php
                        }//for loop end 
            ?>
```

Comment: And what issue are you getting?

Comment: hi , i am able to fetch value but it is always fetching the last value of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by passing value in function:

```
<?php
$subtil=$_GET['subtil1'];
$til=$_GET['til1'];
 $files = glob("images/image/$til/$subtil/*.*");
            $count=count($files);
            for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) 
            { 

              echo "<div class='pitem entry item-w1 item-h1'  style='padding: 15px;'>";

              $image = $files[$i];
              echo "<img src='".$image."' class='img-responsive' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid black;'>"."";
              echo "<br>";
              $detatil="delete.php?image=$image&til=$til&subtil=$subtil";
              echo"<span style='float: center;padding-top: 10px;'><button type='submit' onclick=myFunction('$detail') name='submit' value='Send' class='btn btn-primary'>Delete</button></span>";

              //echo $detatil;
              echo "</div>";
?>

            <script>

            function myFunction(url) {
                  var r=confirm("Do you want to leave page!");
                if (r)
                {
                    //write redirection code
                    window.location = url;
                }
                else
               {
                    //do nothing
                }    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
            }
            </script>  

            <?php
                        }//for loop end 
            ?>
```

Comment: check I have remove single quotes from onclick add in method

Comment: <a type='submit' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?image=".$image."&til=".$til."&subtil=".$subtil."' name='submit' value='Send' class='btn btn-primary'>Delete</a></span>";